# How to override Jackson ObjectMapper configuration for Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

In a Spring Boot/Spring Cloud Stream application, we're using the Kafka binder. I've noticed that when deserializing Kafka messages that include a `ZonedDateTime` property, Jackson is automatically changing the time zone (to UTC) even when the serialized form includes time zone (eg, `20210101084239+0200`).
After some research, I discovered this is a default deserialization feature that can be disabled, so I added the following in one of my `@Configuration` classes:

```java
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer objectMapperCustomizer() {
        return builder ->  {
            builder.featuresToDisable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE);
            //... other custom config...
        };
```

But that doesn't work, presumably because the ObjectMapper that Spring Cloud Stream (or the Kafka binder) uses is not constructed from the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` that's configured in the application context :-(.

After some more research, I found someone claiming that it was necessary to override Spring Messaging's `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` since it creates its own `ObjectMapper`. So I added this:

```java
    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2MessageConverter springMessagingJacksonConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.getObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE, false);

        return converter;
    }
```

Unfortunately, that still didn't work. I still am getting `ZonedDateTime` objects deserialized ignoring the time zone info in the JSON values.

So what bean creates the `ObjectMapper` used by Spring Cloud Stream Kafka binder, and how can I customize its configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in discussion comments below and [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2215), there is a bug in Spring Cloud Stream that it's not using the `ObjectMapper` from the Spring application context in places that it should.

Having said that, a workaround is to define your own `Serde<>` @Bean which calls the `JsonSerde<>` constructor that takes an `ObjectMapper`, which is injected from the app context. For example:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public Serde<SomeClass> someClassSerde(ObjectMapper jsonMapper) {
        return new JsonSerde<SomeClass>(SomeClass.class, jsonMapper);
    }
}
```

The downside to this workaround is that you have to do it for every target type that you want to serialize/deserialize in messages.

Answer (score 0):

please see [spring boot reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.spring-mvc.customize-jackson-objectmapper)

> If you want to replace the default ObjectMapper completely, either define a @Bean of that type and mark it as @Primary or, if you prefer the builder-based approach, define a Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder @Bean. Note that, in either case, doing so disables all auto-configuration of the ObjectMapper.

Comment: `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` is similar to those, but lets you customize, instead of totally replace, the ObjectMapper builder. That's what I already did, and I know it's being used because I see it in `ObjectMapper` instances I inject into my own classes. But Spring Cloud Stream/Kafka isn't using it for some reason.

Comment: Can you please raise an issue - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues and reference this discussion? i see that `AbstractMessageChannelBinder`, `BindingService`, `BindingsLifecycleController`, etc are all creating new instance of ObjectMapper when they really need one from AC

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky is there any workaround at all right now? I must add a mix-in to support deserialization of some third-party types.

Comment: For message converters we do pull ObjetMapper form the AC, so I am not sure how these other classes affect you. Perhaps if you can create a small project with bare minimum that reproduces the issue and push it to guthub somewhere, we can look and see if there is a potential workaround

Comment: It'll take some time to put together a minimal project to demonstrate. In the meantime, here is the stack trace where Jackson is failing to deserialize a LocalDateRange (which I have added a mixin for to the AC `ObjectMapper`)
https://gist.github.com/erizzo/cb5b8b0756bdc3f6323df9117a8f782c

Comment: I think I have worked around it by defining my own `Serde<>` @Bean which creates a standard `JsonSerde<>` but uses the AC `ObjectMapper` in the `JSonSerde` constructor.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky issue is created [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2215)